# a Vue.Js simple example gives me a blank page

Tags: vue.js, command-line-interface

So I wanted to deploy a VueJS app in my shared hosting server.
For that, I followed a simple tutorial, with SSH access to my server I've installed vue CLI than I used this two commands :

```
     vue init webpack myproject
```

Than

```
    npm run build
```

After that when I access to my index.html it's just a blank page with no Errors...

I though the problem is in my .htaccess file, I tried to change it to :

```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteBase /
     RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
  </IfModule>
```

I still get the blank page, does anyone know how I can fix this please? thanks.

Comment: Does your webserver serve the `dist` folder? Do you see the default project when you go to `example.com/dist` or `example.com/dist/index.html`?

Comment: Are you hosting the site in a sub-directory on your server?

Comment: Maybe you need run `npm run  build` to generate the dist directory first！